# vba comparing similar lists

Tags: excel, list

I have 2 sheets with very similar lists. Example

```
Column A   Column B
1          1
2          3
3          3.5
4          4
4.5        5
5
```

I should add the missing elements to B and then delete the extra elements from B.I'm not looking for copypaste, this numbers are actually links and I'll run macros before copying and deleting. so

```
Call add(2)
Call add(4.5)
Call remove(3.5)
```

Is there a faster way than going

```
for (all elements in A)
   for (all elements in B)
      if (they match) then mark as ok
delete all non marked in B
add all non marked in A
```

It feels slow, and I don't know how to 'mark'

Comment: When saying you can't copy/paste because the numbers are links, do you mean the column A holds links, formulas, whatever; while column B holds just are just values? If so, did you consider pasting values only?

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim varSheetA As Variant
    Dim varSheetB As Variant
    Dim strRangeToCheck As String
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long

    strRangeToCheck = "A1:IV65536"
    ' If you know the data will only be in a smaller range, reduce the size of the ranges above.
    Debug.Print Now
    varSheetA = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strRangeToCheck)
    varSheetB = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(strRangeToCheck) ' or whatever your other sheet is.
    Debug.Print Now

    For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
        For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
            If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then
                ' Cells are identical.
                ' Do nothing.
            Else
                ' Cells are different.
                ' Code goes here for whatever it is you want to do.
            End If
        Next iCol
    Next iRow

End Sub
```

Try using this setup and within the else statement you need to create a print string so it can say if this value matches this